# Idea of the likelihood function $p(x[0];A) = p(x[0]-A)$

Tags: probability, statistics

Given a model
$$x[0]=A+w[0]$$

Assume that $w[0]$ follows an arbitrary PDF $p(w[0])$.

A solution book gave the solution as the first step:

$$p_x(x[0];A) = p_w(x[0]-A) = p(w[0]-A)$$

Why is it that the likelihood could "transform" into the middle and right term? Could somebody explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X=c+W$ and $f_W$ is the PDF of $W$, then for every Borel set $B$ one has $$
P[X\in B]=P[W\in B-c]=\int_{B-c}f_W(w)\mathrm dw.
$$
The change of variable $x=w+c$ (*what else?*) yields 
$$
P[X\in B]=\int_Bf_W(x-c)\mathrm dx.
$$
This holds for every Borel set $B$ hence $f_X$ is the function defined by, for every $x$,
$$
f_X(x)=f_W(x-c).
$$

Comment: Which generates the question: which textbook(s) are you using?

Comment: Fundamentals of Statistical Signal Processing, Volume I: Estimation Theory

Comment: And they don't explain this stuff, in "Fundamentals of Statistical Signal Processing, Volume I: Estimation Theory"?

Comment: nope they didn't, they assumed....i think it's coz it's a post grad textbook